# Creating a route with Spring in Netbeans

Tags: spring, netbeans, routes

I know this is a pretty basic issue, but I struggle hard with it...
I'd like to create a bunch of routes with the Spring framework in the Netbeans IDE, I have created a test @Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public ModelAndView thisIsATest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return (new ModelAndView("myTestPage.jsp"));
    }
}
```

myTestPage.jsp is a JSP file in the WEB-INF/jsp/ folder, and the HelloController class is in the Source Packages/ folder within a controller java package.

When I start the server, I can acces the root '/index.htm' that displays the index.jsp page (from the redirect.jsp file), but when I try to access '/test' or '/test.htm' I get a 404 error...

I really don't know how to make a Spring controller to work, and I did many tutorials without success.

Answer (score 0):

In your applications web.xml make sure you have something like this. This will allow access to all your jsp pages. Add any other filters you may need here too.

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: My file is quite similar, but the servlet-mapping tag looks like this: <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: You have to add the url pattern for *.jsp as well and every other type of files that you are going to serve up.